# В requests запросе получаю ошибку 404

Tags: python, парсер

```
match_id = 1-a7e2ba5e-4491-4d4e-8dea-e80055f5e710
stats_of_match = requests.get(f"https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/games/{match_id}", headers=api_header)
print(stats_of_match)
```

Результат `<Response [404]>`

Comment: Это значит, что сервер не может найти данные согласно запросу. Возможно опечатка в url.

Comment: Хотя в данном случае, опечатки нет, просто для того чтобы попасть на указанный url, необходимо проходить аутентификацию, без нее не пускает.

Comment: аутентификацию я сделал, странно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать строковый тип переменной:

```
match_id = "1-a7e2ba5e-4491-4d4e-8dea-e80055f5e710"
stats_of_match = requests.get(f"https://open.faceit.com/data/v4/games/{match_id}", headers=api_header)
print(stats_of_match)
```